# Find Something in List of Objects, where object value is equal to string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

My classes

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<AuthToken> Tokens { get; set; } = new List<AuthToken>();
}

public class AuthToken
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public long Created { get; set; }
    public long Dispose { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string LocalisationInfo { get; set; }
    public string MachineInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select AuthToken object, which `string Token` is equal to ``` 123 `

```cs
var user = cnx._Users
              .Where(x => x.Tokens.Contains(/*Tokens.Token object equal to 123 */))
```

In simply `Where` condition I can only compare two `AuthToken` objects. I need to compare `AuthToken.Token` strings.

Finally I want to select User who has `Token` I used. In this case its `123`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can 'chain' multiple linq calls to get the result you want...

```
var user = cnx._Users.Where(u => u.Tokens.Any(atoken => atoken.Token == "123")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve it like below

```
var user = cnx._Users.Where(x => x.Tokens.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Token == "123") != null);
```